# jest shallow render find by class excluding

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am testing a class like:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Features {...props}/>);
expect(wrapper.find('.Feature__Item:not(.Feature__Showmore)').length).toBe(2);
```

But, I am getting an error like this: 
Error: Enzyme::Selector does not support pseudo-element or pseudo-class selectors.

How can I work around this limitation?

**Update**: Interesting observation, when I wrote the following in the debug console: `wrapper.find('.Feature__Item').findWhere(a => a.hasClass('Feature__Showmore') === false).length`

The output was:

```
0:Object {nodeType: "host", type: "li", props: Object, …}
1:Object {nodeType: "function", type: , props: Object, …}
2:Object {nodeType: "host", type: "li", props: Object, …}
3:Object {nodeType: "function", type: , props: Object, …}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found another way which did the trick:

```
expect(wrapper.find('.Feature__Item').not('.Feature__Showmore').length).toBe(2);
```

Comment: You can also use `.toHaveLength(2)` instead of `.length).toBe(2)`

Answer (score 1):

You could try with `findWhere`:

```
expect(wrapper.find('.Feature__Item').findWhere(a => a.hasClass('Feature__Showmore') === false).length).toBe(2);
```

This will first get all the elements having class `Feature__Item` and then exclude from this list the ones which don't have `Feature__Showmore` class.

Comment: This makes sense to me, but I expect 2 and I get 4 for some reason.

Comment: Check what is actually rendered with `console.log(wrapper.debug())`